# How to check if audioplayer is paused while loading multiple viewcontrollers

Tags: iphone

In `playpauseAction` Method execution it will play audio file as well as load multiple `viewcontrollers`

```
-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender 
{

 if  

  ([audioPlayer isPlaying]){

 [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

      [audioPlayer pause];

  } else {

 [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

      [audioPlayer play];

      self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11 target:self selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
  }  

}
```

While loading these `view controllers` just want to check in every `viewcontroller` that if `audioplayer` is paused then `invalidate timer` if not then continue loading of `viewcontroller` with `NSTimer`

```
- (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender
{

FirstViewController *viewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];

viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

if  

    ([audioPlayer pause]){

    [timer invalidate];

    } else {

   self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:23 target:self selector:@selector(secondViewController) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];  

}  
[viewController release];
}
```

My problem is when i add if statement in `displayviewAction` method it gives me red warning message that `statement requires expression of scalar type (void invalid)`.

But `if statement`  in the  `playpauseAction` works fine.

Why the `if statement` of `displayviewAction` is giving red warning message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVAudioPlayer's pause is defined as:

```
-(void)pause
```

so writing:

```
if([audioPlayer pause]) {...}
```

corresponds to write:

```
if(void) {...}
```

and void is not a scalar type, exactly what the error message tells you.

Probably your intention was to check if the audio player was paused, that is it is not playing :

```
if([audioPlayer isPlaying]==NO) {...}
```